# i am fetching data from loop..if more than day task is not exist how i get zero instead of null?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
  SELECT 'task_id',date,'task_name',count('task_id') AS total 
  FROM tasks 
  where date between adddate(now(),-7) and now() group by date
```

```
 for($i=0; $i <= $row_date= mysqli_fetch_array($record); $i++)
  {
        $total_task[$i]=$row_date['total'];

    }
```

it return undefined off set on index

```
    echo $total_task[0];
    echo $total_task[1];
    echo $total_task[2];
```

up to so on

i want return 0 for all 6 index if task is not exist

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish with `$i <= $row_date = mysqli_fetch_array`? mysql_fetch returns arrays/objects, NOT an integer to be compared.

Comment: @NaveedAbbas Are you sure that your query returns amy data?

Comment: You're using incorrect identifier qualifiers here. Look up that term and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Of course, ^ that comment will go to deaf ears. Plus, who knows what API you're using to connect with.

Comment: yeah i m sure if dates have some result.. it returns properly.. if the data not exist on tha date.. it return nothing.. i just want to return zero if data not exist on that date @splash58

Comment: MySQL can't. Do it by PHP

Comment: then how i can do it in php @ splash58... Actually i'm using bar chart who shows the daily performance.. how many task are completed on monday,tuesday  up to so on

Comment: Make array with all dates and default other values. Then replace it with result of query. Dates absent in DB will stay with default data

Comment: @ splash58 I'm beginner i don't know about much

Answer (score -1):

Try this.  proper looping and (int) casting makes NULL into 0,

```
$total_task = array();
while(false !==( $row_date= mysqli_fetch_assoc($record)))
{
    $total_task[]= (int)$row_date['total'];

}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\TMA_Dept\testing.php on line 16..it show this

Comment: you must have missed something from what I put, such as the `(` it has to be this `while(false !==( $row_date= mysqli_fetch_array($record)))`

Comment: You don't have to have the `false!==` in the while, the `fetch_array()` will return false of no more rules and end the while. Also, `fetch_array()` isn't the way to go, pick `fetch_assoc()` or `fetch_row()` :)

Comment: I know, but I'm old school like that, it makes more sense to me because = is assignment and not comparison.   I agree with the fetch_assoc, but i just copied that havent used mysqli in like 3 years.  PDO for me...

Comment: one of my IT guys is coping over a DB to our new server with 60mill rows in... ugg I hate waiting.